# render 'report/cover' throw missing template error

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a controller called ReportController,it has an action `cover` and I have view `cover.html.erb`, In another controller, I have a cover action, I tried to render `report/cover`, error thrown:

```
Missing template /report/cover with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:json],     :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :rabl, :jbuilder]}. Searched in: * "/avnext/avalanche_app/app/views" * "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/apitome-0.0.4/app/views" * "/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/devise-2.2.3/app/views" * "/avnext/avalanche_app" * "
```

but if I render `report/cover.html.erb`, it rendered fine. 
I dont understand why i could not use `report/cover` directly?

Comment: Can you show us the code how you are rendering?

Comment: @Pavan                                                                                                               
      `render 'report/cover.html.erb'` this works. `render 'report/cover` doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

It is wired, when I write unit test for this action, I have to do

```
 it 'render view' do
    get :show, :id => @result3.id, format: :html
    response.should render_template('report/cover')
  end
```

but in my code, I have to write `render report/cover.html.erb`